# Having trouble figuring out how to approach this exercise #R scraping #extracting web data

Tags: r, dataframe, screen-scraping

So, sometimes I need to get some data from the web organizing it into a dataframe and waste a lot of time doing it manually. I've been trying to figure out how to optimize this proccess, and I've tried with some R scraping approaches, but couldn't get to do it right and I thought there could be an easier way to do this, can anyone help me out with this?

Fictional exercise:

Here's a webpage with countries listed by continents: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_continents

Each country name is also a link that leads to another webpage (specific of each country, e.g. https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angola).

I would like as a final result to get a data frame with number of observations (rows) = number of countries listed and 4 variables (colums) as ID=Country Name, Continent=Continent it belongs to, Language=Official language (from the specific webpage of the Countries) and Population = most recent population count (from the specific webpage of the Countries).

Which steps should I follow in R in order to be able to reach to the final data frame?

Answer (score 0):

[This will probably get you most of the way](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html). You'll want to play around with the different nodes and probably do some string manipulation (clean up) after you download what you need.